# What framework is the best option for creating a gaming website?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am starting a gaming website which will require exchanging data between a gamer and the gaming server on regular basis. Since i am new to Java and i have worked with a bit of Java Beans, i would like to know that based on my requirements, which framework would be a good one among the following:

- EJB
- Spring
- Struts

I know that it is possible to do this with every framework, but of course certain frameworks are more preferred in some cases.

Since i am new to these technologies, i am therefore not sure which one to follow for creating the gaming website. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no one best answer for your question. You can get only opinions.

Considering the Lean concept (see Eric Ries), I recommend you to start with whatever you know how to use better. Focus on the idea/business, instead of technology. You're not Google at this stage.

Make a prototype, see how it's going and build a small set of features in each iteration.
There are so many things you'll learn along the way...you simply have no idea.

Comment: The only thing i know is JavaBeans using which i can just create a constructor, set and get functions and another class for database transactions and other models. Do you think that would suffice in this case?

Comment: Ah...so you're really at the beginning, but no worries. Then keep going with this if you already started to understand its basics. Nevertheless, you first have to learn more. Here are some nice free examples for EJB and Java EE related features: http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/index.html See http://blog.adam-bien.com/ for more advanced stuff.